# In React, is it possible to skip re-render after setState if the state doesn't affect rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

E.g. let's say I have a hook for making an API request:

```
function useApi(...) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ fetching: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({ fetching: true });
    fetch(...)
      .then(() => setState({ fetching: false }));
  }, [...]);

  return { fetching: state.fetching };
}
```

Sometimes, the state of `useApi` affects rendering:

```
function Foo() {
  const { fetching } = useApi(...);

  if (fetching) {
    return 'Loading';
  }
  return 'Foo';
}
```

Other times, it doesn't affect rendering:

```
function Bar() {
  useApi(...);

  return 'Bar';
}
```

When `setState` in `useApi` doesn't affect rendering, is it possible to avoid re-rendering the component?

I know it doesn't affect performance much, but it's good to know if this is possible.

Comment: You could be passing a parameter to the `useApi` and according to its value not use the `setState` in the hook.

Comment: No, there's no way with your current setup to prevent a re-render. You can use things like hook dependency lists of memoization to reduce the impact of re-renders, but you can't stop them. Or as others mentioned update your hook so a parameter controls the re-render logic. But if you aren't using the returned values of the hook then you probably shouldn't be using it. You should just do something like directly fire off the fetch request in the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `boolean` flag to determine if you want to change `useApi` hook state in time or not.

```
const { fetching } = useApi(..., flag);
```

and then inside `useApi` hook:

```
function useApi(..., flag) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ fetching: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    flag && setState({ fetching: true });

    fetch(...)
      .then(() => {
         flag && setState({ fetching: false }));
         // do other stuff
      });
  }, [...]);

  return { fetching: state.fetching };
}
```